# Token Session and Post Token always different although from the same paramater

Tags: php, forms, session, token

i'm generate a token for my form like this:

```
/*** set a form token ***/
$token = md5( uniqid(rand(), true) );


/*** set the session form token ***/
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $token;
```

and put hidden input in my form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

but when i submit the pages and compare the token it give me a different token id. can anyone tell me am i doing something wrong?

Comment: that means you are regenerating the token before comparison

Comment: maybe use `$_SESSION['form_token']` instead of `$token` in your input form.

Comment: how come it regenerating new token when it already the same in value before it submitted. and i already put $_SESSION['form_token'] in my form but it just the same. the id is changing and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you only (re)generate a token if the form is not submitted yet.

```
<?php
// Process request OR show form..
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
    // check if we receive a token
    if(isset($_POST['form_token'])) 
    {
        // compare the token
        if($_POST['form_token'] === $_SESSION['form_token']) 
        {
            // do the magic here...
            unset($_SESSION['form_token']);
        } else {
            die('No token match');
        }
    } else {
        die('No token found');
    }
} else {
    $token = md5( uniqid(rand(), true));
    $_SESSION['form_token'] = $token;

    // print form with hidden token..
}
```

Comment: thanks it work, but can you suggest me how i prevent it show error like this Notice: Undefined index: form_token in because this code : // compare the token
        if($_POST['form_token'] === $_SESSION['form_token']). it happen because i'm submit and submit again. thanks

Comment: forget it, i commented in             unset($_SESSION['form_token']); and it work, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting your site in an incognito window. If this works, you need to delete all your browsers' cookies and other site plugins because your session has been cached. It's trying to match sessions from an earlier time.