# $_SESSION[''token] never matching $_POST['token']

Tags: php, forms, function, session, post

I'm building a form and securing it against CSRF and such.

```
session_start();
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$_SESSION['token'] = null;

//other code to check and control form

function create_token() {
    $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;

    return $token;
}

$newToken = create_token();
```

Then in my form I put this `<input name=:"token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($newToken);?>">`.

Now if I want to verify the form submission by doing this:

```
function user_submit_check() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])) { 
        return false;
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['token'])) {
        return false;
    }
    //This next 'if' statement always returns false
    if ($_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['token']) {
        return false;
    }
return true;
}

if (user_submit_token() === true) {
    //process user input
} else {
    die("There is a problem with verification.");
}
```

The problem is that `user_submit_check()` always returns false, (see comment in function). So far I can't find any solution as to why this is happening. A lot of sources state that this method works.

Also I have tried to manually check `$_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['token']` by using `echo ("posted input token" . $_POST['token'] . "stored in $_SESSION" . $_SESSION['token']);`

This shows that both tokens are in fact the same, on paper at least.
I'm probably missing something but i'm kinda new to securing forms in PHP.

**EDIT:**
Maybe useful to share, i'm doing all security and all the html/form stuff on one page currently. I use this: `<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` to execute the scripts... (checking for empty form fields and so on).

**EDIT 2:**
Thanks @CBroe, for pointing out the bad HTML without "" on all the attributes.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568547/token-session-and-post-token-always-different-although-from-the-same-paramater/27568857#27568857

Comment: _“This shows that both tokens are in fact the same, on paper at least”_ – use `var_dump` to output both of those values, separately, not by concatenating them into a string first. What does that result in? (Show the _exact_ result by copy&paste please.)

Comment: Will do, result follows soon. Thanks

Comment: check datatype of both

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, you saved me! They are in fact different from each other.. Going to resolve this first.. I'll update the post when I have the fix. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @AjitKumar PHP does type juggling so that does not make any sense

Comment: @G4Hu: And what’s the difference? If it’s just an additional space or something, then check how you put the token into the hidden field’s `value` attribute … if you messed that up even by a little, that’ll make the comparison fail. (And btw., you should really use quotes around attribute values in HTML.)

Comment: @CBroe: The difference is the tokens themselves, they differ somehow. So i'm trying to fix my code atm.. kinda done working today tho, so continuing later. And thanks for pointing out the missing "" in my HTML, its a mistake typing (my real code does have them)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if item has been posted or not 1st.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{    
    if(isset($_POST['token'])) 
    {       
        // Test to see if tokens match
        if($_SESSION['token'] === $_POST['token']) 
        {           
            // process user input
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
        } else {
            die('Tokens did not match');
        }
    } else {
        die('No token found');
    }
} else {

    $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    ?>

<form>
<input name=token type=hidden value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
</form>

<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the session is set before you echo it

```
<input name="token" type=hidden 
       value=<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['token'])) ? $_SESSION['token'] : ''?>>
```

`PHP` code should be very simple for what you are trying to achieve:

```
session_start();
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['token'], $_SESSION['token'])){

    if ($_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']){
        echo 'token match';
    }else{
        echo 'token do not match';
    }

}else{
    $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}
```